# Mapstruct problem: Unknown property error

Tags: gradle, lombok, mapstruct, annotation-processing

Im using mapstruct and lombok together and experiencing some problems with it:

```java
EntityMapper.java:10: error: Unknown property "id" in result type Entity. Did you mean "null"?
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
                      ^
```

My Entity and EntityDto classes:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Entity {

    private int id;

    private String property;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class EntityDto {

    private String property;
}
```

EntityMapper:

```java
@Mapper(implementationName = "MapStruct<CLASS_NAME>")
public interface EntityMapper {

    // neither of them work
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    //@Mapping(target = "id", defaultValue = "0")
    Entity map(EntityDto dto);

    EntityDto map(Entity entity);

}
```

In this configuration it leads to compile-time error. So i tried to comment out @Mapping annotation. It compiled, but it maps all properties to null. MapStructEntityMapper generated implementation:

```java
public class MapStructEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {
    public MapStructEntityMapper() {
    }

    public Entity map(EntityDto dto) {
        if (dto == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Entity entity = new Entity();
            return entity;
        }
    }

    public EntityDto map(Entity entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            EntityDto entityDto = new EntityDto();
            return entityDto;
        }
    }
}
```

I found couple answers that are talking about annotation processors, but take a look at my build.gradle file:

```
// MapStruct - Entity-DTO mapper                             
implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.1.Final'         
annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.1.
compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.1.0'   
// Util                                                      
// lombok                                                    
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'               
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'       
testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'           
testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
```

Some time it worked if i compile without @Mapping annotation and then run with this annotation, but now even this does not work.

Comment: here is [github repo](https://github.com/VayKekaz/mapstructtest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a problem with the `lombok-mapstruct-binding`.

That should be in the same scope as the processors. You need to put it under `annotationProcessor` and not `compile`

Answer (score 0):

annotationProcessor for mapstruct should be below annotationProcessor for lombok.